# What is the easiest way to upload a front-end only website to the web?

Tags: web, hosting

Suppose I have created a website that only cosnists of html, css, and javascript. Only Client side. What is an easy and cheap way to upload it to the web? Any hosting services that allow you to upload it for free?

Comment: I don't know of any hosting services which charge *by the upload process*.  Whatever means your hosting provider supports for uploading would likely be as easy as any other.

Comment: This means to upload a simple website like this and a fully developed web app you have to pay the same?

Comment: What you pay depends on the hosting service that you buy.  It doesn't really have anything to do with what files you upload or how you upload them.  If there are features you don't plan to use and those features cost extra then you probably don't want to buy those features.  It's not really clear what you're asking or why.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a shot for Heroku [free instance](https://www.heroku.com/about).

[Getting started with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-play-on-heroku) guide.

Comment: how many client side websites liek this can you upload ?? One? or more?

Comment: You can also check [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) or - if you really need performance - [Free Tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) on Amazon Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku, OpenShift, etc. are thought to upload both back-end and front-end.

Try [Hostinger](https://www.hostinger.com/). You can have 5 sites for free, unlimited if you pay.

You can upload only .html, .css and .js and don't complicate your life (although you can do backend as well if you want).

I tried it yesterday for the first time. I uploaded 3 files (index.html, docs.js, docs.css), which I had already written, using a web form. And that's it. My web was up and working.